# New Software on Ubuntu Hardy Heron(8.04)

Tags: firefox, 8.04

I am using ubuntu 8.04 because of my hardware restrictions.
I followed the steps to install latest firefox as i can use but i get firefox 3.6 could not found response:

> For Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy) Users
>
> ```
> deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu hardy main
> deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu hardy main
> ```
>
> Save and exit the file
>
> Now you need to add PPA GPG key
>
> ```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 247510BE
> ```
>
> Update the source list
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```
>
> Install Firefox 3.6
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install firefox-3.6
> ```
>
> If you already have a version of Firefox 3.5 installed from a repo
>   then upgrade using the following command
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 8.04 is not supported by Ubuntu since May 12, 2011.  The Hardy repositories were removed, so that means you can only install software through .deb packages.

If you have hardware restrictions, I suggest downloading [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/), which is an official Ubuntu derivative that requires less hardware restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

8.04 is no longer supported and removed from the server.

However, the [link](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/) provided is where the older distros are now kept.

Firefox 3.6 can be downloaded here [source](http://www.filecrop.com/firefox-3.6-deb.html)